# Capture the value of an HTML variable

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to read the value of a variable in an HTML page, and report it to Google Analytics.
The line in question is this:

```
<h1 id="results-heading">Your search for <span class="query"></span> returned <span class="total-results"></span> result(s).</h1>
```

I want to capture the value of the "query" variable.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

#### retrieving the query value

Assuming you are using jQuery, you can get the text present inside the `span.query` using this:

```
var queryValue = $('span.query').text()
```

#### sending to Google analytics

Then you may send this information to Google Analytics using one of the supported mechanisms that is the most appropriate to your use case (which is not described in the question). Examples of how this may be done:

**event**

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'you-know',
  eventAction: 'whatever',
  eventLabel: queryValue
});
```

(cf. [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)).

**custom dimension**

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', queryValue);
```

(cf [custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)).

Comment: These is my first steps in GA/tags, and I'm no programming pro :-). I currently insert the <!-- Google Tag Manager --> snippet in my pages to track page views, etc. Where do I place the `var` statement? Can I send the value as part of the snippet?

Comment: You may want to update your question and precise that you're using Google tag manager, and explain how/where you would like to view the "query" information in Google Analytics